# Can't build a project with Postsharp 4.1.14

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, postsharp

I have a project which references a postsharp 4.1.14. When I build a project the error occurred. Postsharp is installed by nuget package. There is .net version 4.0 installed on computer, but Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper.GetPlatformSDKLocation method is from .net 4.5. Can I use different version of postsharp? Is there another way to fix my problem?

Error   1   The "PostSharp30GetInstalledFrameworks" task failed unexpectedly.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper.GetPlatformSDKLocation(System.String, System.Version)'.
   at PostSharp.MSBuild.PostSharp30GetInstalledFrameworks.b__5(<>f__AnonymousType0`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier0)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at PostSharp.MSBuild.PostSharp30GetInstalledFrameworks.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)   ConsoleApplication1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostSharp 4.x requires at least Visual Studio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5 installed on the development machine or build server (http://doc.postsharp.net/requirements). Your project can still target .NET 4.0, .NET 4.5 is needed only at build-time.

If you have only older versions of VS and .NET installed, then you can use PostSharp 3.x, which is still supported and works with VS 2010 and .NET 4.0.